# Has anybody succeeded in using JBoss AOP in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, aop

HI,
I'm failing to deploy my application using JBoss AOP within a Apache Tomcat 6.0.16 server.

I'm using the VM arg

> -Djava.system.class.loader=org.jboss.aop.standalone.SystemClassLoader

I also have added the jboss aop jars to the classpath.

The server and the webapp is starting but I'm getting this error:

> INFO: Unknown loader org.jboss.aop.standalone.SystemClassLoader@923e30 class org.jboss.aop.standalone.SystemClassLoader

In consequence Jboss aop is not working.

By accident I found this link:
http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:xmIPvJaB7mEJ:mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-dev/200208.mbox/%253C20020822170212.55248.qmail%40icarus.apache.org%253E+tomcat+%22Unkown+loader%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=at

In this code segment I found my error message which is printed when the loader is no URLClassLoader.

> if (!(loader instanceof URLClassLoader))
>    +            if (!(loader instanceof URLClassLoader)) {
>    +                String cp=getClasspath( loader );
>    +                if( cp==null ) {
>    +                    log.info( "Unknown loader " + loader + " " + loader.getClass());

I'm not sure if that's the reason for the problem but it may be.

Does anyone have a hint for me how to make this work?
Is JBoss AOP simply not working with Tomcat standalone (Using JBoss is not an option at the moment).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it looks like Tomcat explicitly rejects any classloaders that it doesn't recognise as `URLClassloader`. Tomcat running within JBoss uses JBoss's own classloaders.

Comment: Why not just use AspectJ? That works within tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to start tomcat normally and then, on the threads you want jboss AOP, set their context classloader to `org.jboss.aop.standalone.SystemClassLoader`